# Does django cassandra engine allows to query on multiple keyspaces of same cluster

Tags: python, django, cassandra, django-orm

I have multiple keyspaces in cassandra database each having few tables.
I have done Cassandra connection from settings.py, but don't know how to change the keyspace name for some query in Django-ORM.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the keyspace for each model that is defined by django_cassandra_engine library. User model in below is a simple example of what you want.

```
class User(DjangoCassandraModel):
    _table_name = "users"
    __keyspace__ = "yourKeyspaceName"
    user_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
```

and then you can use `User.objects.filter()` to make query on your model.

Comment: if this answer has helped you please thick my answer as correct answer and upvote that.